# Production ready LAMP stack - in Docket, Rocket etc

Tags: docker, lamp, production-environment, server-configuration, rocket

Id like to use cloud hosting platforms like Digital Ocean or Linode, but Im a bit concerned about my server configuration, its not something Ive had experience of, does any one know if there is a Docker package (or any other environment file) that i could upload with a locked down production ready LAMP stack ?

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use default containers (nginx phpfpm mysql) and mount inside volumes with config files.